# Node.js variable scope outside the function

Tags: node.js

I have done lots of reading on the asynchronous property of our node.js and about the power of callbacks.

But, I don't understand if I define a function and change the value of the variable inside that function, then why is it not available outside the function.

Let me show by an example on the code that I have been working on.

```
var findRecords = function(db, callback) {

var cursor =db.collection('meta').find({"title":"The Incredible Hulk: Return of the Beast  [VHS]"}, {"asin":1,_id:0}).limit(1);
pass="";
cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      if (doc != null) {
          var arr =  JSON.stringify(doc).split(':');
          key = arr[1];
          key = key.replace(/^"(.*)"}$/, '$1');
          pass =key;
          console.log(pass); //Gives correct output
      } 

   });

   console.log(pass)  //Does not give the correct output

};



MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);

  findRecords(db, function() {
      db.close();
  });
});
```

Here when printing the value of pass inside the function it gives the new value assigned but when printing the second time outside the function it does not give the new value.

How can this problem be removed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 1):

```
let pass = 'test';

[1, 2, 3].map(function(value) {
  let pass = value;
  // local scope: 1, 2, 3
  console.log(pass);
}); 

console.log(pass); // => test

// ------------------------------

let pass = 'test';

[1, 2, 3].map(function(value) {
  pass = value;
  // local scope: 1, 2, 3
  console.log(pass);
}); 

// the last value from the iteration
console.log(pass); // => 3

// ------------------------------

// we omit the initial definition

[1, 2, 3].map(function(value) {
  // note the usage of var
  var pass = value;
  // local scope: 1, 2, 3
  console.log(pass);
}); 

// the variable will exist because `var`
console.log(pass); // => 3

// ------------------------------

// we omit the initial definition

[1, 2, 3].map(function(value) {
  // note the usage of var
  let pass = value;
  // local scope: 1, 2, 3
  console.log(pass);
}); 

// the variable will not exist because using let
console.log(pass); // => undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
var pass="";
var that = this;
cursor.forEach(function(err, doc) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      if (doc != null) {
          var arr =  JSON.stringify(doc).split(':');
          key = arr[1];
          key = key.replace(/^"(.*)"}$/, '$1');
          pass =key;
          console.log(pass); //Gives correct output
      } 

   }, that);
console.log(pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pass=""
first declare it and try this var pass="";